# In case expression else part is not getting executed and giving wrong output

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    e_id        NUMBER(10),
    col_id      NUMBER(10),
    col_ans     VARCHAR2(30),
    col_pos_id  NUMBER(10)
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,7,null,29);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,45,'test',30);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,13,'test1',31);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,14,'test2',32);
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,15,'test3',33);

--reference table
CREATE TABLE lookup_table (
    col_id     NUMBER(10),
    col_value  VARCHAR2(20)
);
INSERT INTO lookup_table VALUES(29,'demo');

DB version: Oracle 18c
```

I have two tables one for transactional and the other one is a reference table. I need to get the output based on columns `col_ans` and `col_pos_id` and need to fetch the value from the reference table as per the below requirement.

I need to check `col_id` equals 7 only. And all operation needs to happen on this `col_id` only.
In my dataset suppose for `e_id` 1 we have `col_id` as 7 (and this 7 will always be there)
then need to check `col_pos_id` if this is 29 then need to fetch the value for this id from the reference table and concatenate another value with the logic as if `col_id` is 45 then need to fetch `col_ans` column value ELSE need to print only the `col_pos_id` value.

Expected Output:

```
+------+-------------+--+
| e_id |   output    |  |
+------+-------------+--+
|    1 | demo - test |  |
+------+-------------+--+
```

My attempt:-

```
SELECT t.e_id,
CASE 
WHEN t.col_id = 7 AND t.col_pos_id= 29 THEN 
rt.col_value|| '-'|| (SELECT col_ans FROM test WHERE t.col_id = 45)
ELSE
rt.col_value
END output
FROM test t
JOIN lookup_table rt ON(rt.col_id = t.col_pos_id AND t.col_id = 7 );
```

Here, the only `else` part is getting executed and not getting the expected result.

Comment: What exactly does "not getting the expected result" mean? Please show the output of your query and describe how it is "wrong". You say you're expecting `demo - test` but `"demo"` is not a value in your data. Please explain.

Comment: @Bohemian demo is there in reference table which I am joining based of col_pos_id and fetching this value from reference table

Comment: @AlexPoole No it is giving duplicate entries. I tried using left join also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to scoping the variables. In the sub-query nested inside the `CASE` expression, you use `(SELECT col_ans FROM test WHERE t.col_id = 45)` and `t.col_id` refers to the `t` alias from the outer query where the only matching row has a `col_id` value of `7` and so `7 = 45` is false and the nested sub-query will never match any rows. What you need to do is either remove the `t.` from that sub-query so that the `col_id` is from the local scope or give the sub-query its own alias and use that:

```sql
SELECT t.e_id,
       CASE 
       WHEN t.col_pos_id= 29
         -- AND t.col_id = 7 /* will always be true due to the JOIN condition */
       THEN rt.col_value || '-' || (SELECT col_ans FROM test x WHERE x.col_id = 45)
       ELSE rt.col_value
       END AS output
FROM   test t
       INNER JOIN lookup_table rt
       ON (rt.col_id = t.col_pos_id AND t.col_id = 7 );
```

or:

```sql
SELECT t.e_id,
       rt.col_value || x.col_ans AS output
FROM   test t
       INNER JOIN lookup_table rt
       ON (rt.col_id = t.col_pos_id AND t.col_id = 7 )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT '-' || col_ans AS col_ans FROM test WHERE col_id = 45) x
       ON (t.col_pos_id= 29);
```

Which, for the sample data, both output:

> | E_ID | OUTPUT |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | demo-test |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a173f7ef5a8277f4b9ad2a55545f1c92)*

Answer (score 1):

This is how I understood the last paragraph.

```
SQL> SELECT t.e_id,
  2         CASE
  3            WHEN t.col_pos_id = 29
  4            THEN
  5                  l.col_value
  6               || CASE WHEN b.col_id = 45 THEN ' - ' || b.col_ans END
  7         END output
  8    FROM test t
  9         JOIN lookup_table l ON l.col_id = t.col_pos_id
 10         LEFT JOIN test b
 11            ON     b.e_id = t.e_id
 12               AND b.col_id = 45
 13   WHERE t.col_id = 7;

      E_ID OUTPUT
---------- -----------------------------------------------------
         1 demo - test

SQL>
```